# How to fetch both active and inactive status columns for multiple accounts linked with single client id

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the below sample data from my Oracle database (The client id's which are having both 350 and 450 account status code within their tagged accounts):

```
select distinct account_number,client_id,account_status_code
from test_client
  join test_client_account_relation on client_id=client_rltsn_id
  join test_account on client_account_id=account_id
where (account_status_code = 350 and account_status_code = 450)
order by 1 desc;
```

and the expected output is :

| Account_Number | Client_id | Account_Status_Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 200897 | 350 |
| ABC456 | 200897 | 450 |
| CDE123 | 300679 | 350 |
| CDE458 | 300679 | 350 |
| CDE541 | 300679 | 450 |

Could someone please help me here with the simplest SQL query to achieve such type of scenario, FYI I had tried by giving two account status code and conditions but that didn't work though and these above 3 columns are coming from two different tables using joins (Client_id is coming from test_client table and Account_number,Account_status_code are coming from test_account table),Please let me know in case you need any further information.

Comment: A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data _and the expected result_. (Use properly formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: have updated my post, Can you please check once and let me know

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated for each row. And a row can never have account_status_code 350 and 450 at the same time.

Comment: Could you please give any suggestions how we can change this above query to get the required output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where (account_status_code = 350 and account_status_code = 450)

Is never going to be true as you can never have a single row where `account_status_code` is both `350` and `450`. What you need to do is look across multiple rows with the same `client_id`.

You can use analytic functions and conditional aggregation to count the number of each `account_status_code` and then filter to only find the client rows which have both:

```sql
SELECT Account_Number,
       Client_id,
       Account_Status_Code
FROM   (
  SELECT Account_Number,
         Client_id,
         Account_Status_Code,
         COUNT(CASE account_status_code WHEN 350 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY client_id) AS has350,
         COUNT(CASE account_status_code WHEN 450 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY client_id) AS has450
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  account_status_code IN (350, 450)
)
WHERE  has350 > 0
AND    has450 > 0;
```

You have only provided the expected output (and not any sample input data):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Account_Number, Client_id, Account_Status_Code) AS
SELECT 'ABC123', 200897, 350 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC456', 200897, 450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CDE123', 300679, 350 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CDE458', 300679, 350 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CDE541', 300679, 450 FROM DUAL;
```

But the query matches all of the input rows:

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | CLIENT_ID | ACCOUNT_STATUS_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC456 | 200897 | 450 |
| ABC123 | 200897 | 350 |
| CDE458 | 300679 | 350 |
| CDE541 | 300679 | 450 |
| CDE123 | 300679 | 350 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TRSwcRhz)